# How to create a query that return custom post type by Advanced Custom Field(ACF) Taxonony?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy, acfpro

you all!

I have categories of **Author**

- 1 - Freelancer
- 2 - Contract
- 3 - Half-time

I have categories of **Books**

- 1 - Novel
- 2 - Fiction

I have a custom post type Author. **Author** has custom fields:

- Name: Text
- Type: Category

I have a custom post type Book. **Book** has custom fields:

- Title: Text
- Author: Taxonomy
- Type: Category
- Pages: Number

I need a query that return ALL BOOKs with Authors that have Contract ID = 1

And

I need a query that return ALL BOOKs with Type = Fiction

Thanks!!!

Comment: ACF fields are basically meta data, so go check the documentation for WP_Query, it has a section dealing with that: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Comment: (Not sure if you can do the whole thing in one query though, you might need to get the IDs of all relevant authors first, and then feed those into a second query, that selects books.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use meta_query to get the desired results:

> I need a query that return ALL BOOKs with Authors that have Contract ID = 1

```
$freelance_books = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'books',
    'meta_key'      => 'book_contract', // Adjust here with your field name
    'meta_value'    => 1
));
```

> I need a query that return ALL BOOKs with Type = Fiction

```
$fiction_books = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'books',
    'meta_key'      => 'book_type', // Adjust here with your field name
    'meta_value'    => 2
));
```